# How to forward my old ISP "Sent" folder emails to a new Gmail account

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I am permanently changing my primary email account from Optimum to Gmail, and have successfully forwarded all the old/current emails in my Optimum "Inbox" to a newly created Gmail folder, using [this procedure](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/21289) provided by Gmail.

But, I don't know how to forward my "Sent" folder from Optimum to Gmail.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I did it by using a third-party email client (Thunderbird) and an IMAP connection between my old email mailbox and my new (Gmail) mailbox. Once the accounts are set up it's simply a question of dragging and dropping from one account to the other.

Comment: I installed Thunderbird, ran it, and it imported my old "Inbox" from my old account into Thunderbird (not to Gmail). But I still haven't figured out how to force it to import my old "Sent" emails from the old account.  I tried Thunderbird "Help", IMAP Syncronization, didn't see anything good there.

Comment: I simply dragged-and-dropped the messages from the Sent folder in one mailbox to the Sent folder in the other mailbox.